# Strange spam messages that go through the Gmail filter

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I use Gmail and find it's very rare to get a spam message through. However I find when I do get a spam message, sometimes the "To:" address is not even my email address:

```
from        Sloane Crawford oraleemayark610@yahoo.com   
reply-to    clarkbid862@yandex.ua  
to          0004045@yahoo.com  
date        18 May 2011 20:52  
subject     Hello sweety. I wanna something new! : 1305748794  
Signed by   yahoo.com
```

How did something without my email address in the "To:" field get into my inbox?

For comedy value this is the message:

> Hello,
>   I have long hair and fine body.
>   Me want to meet you ...
>   I love Usher and strip, I like to communicate via web camera ... & erotic games ...
>   I wanna show myself and communicate with you via video.
>   Wanna get to know each other better - contact me via e-mail, pls.

Comment: What is entered as `To:` email header has very little to do with who receives the email. TO save this question, ask about the relation between email headers and actual recipients in general instead. By the way, we all get our share of spam (or are glad we don't), so there's absolutely no comedy value to this one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to check your message header to find out if it was sent as a forward to you or a bCC. This company is out of Ukraine and has been sending me this type of "Crapmail" as well. The system Administrator is at sysadmin@yandex.ru if you want to voice a complaint.

Answer (score 1):

This is because they must have used the Bcc field.

If you want more details, you should look a the message raw source. Maybe you will get some clue.